# Error al instalar Synfony con escritura en directorios

Tags: symfony, cache, instalacion, symfony5

estoy iniciándome con symfony y al finalizar la instalación sin haber tocado nada me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**mi entorno:** Estoy usando windows 10 y Laragon (xampp vitaminado)

al verificar el directorio me doy cuenta que tiene esto en el atributo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al validar los permisos estos son los marcados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa es la Lista de Usuarios con permisos y todos están iguales con permiso de escritura y lectura.

entonces no se que me hace falta... hay una persistencia en el error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo solucione temporalmente borrando la carpeta cache `dev` al permitir nuevamente a symfony recrear las carpeta y hacerlo con el usuario que ejecuta la consola de comando de symfony permite que se cree con los permisos necesarios.

Update:

la solucion anterior solo resolvia el problema por unos minutos y en cualquier momento volvia a aparecer, por lo tanto investigue un poco mas y no encontre nada... fue necesario editar un archivo de symfony:

Temporalmente lo he solucionado con esto:

```
if(is_dir($dir)){
    chmod($dir, 755);
}
```

como el permiso de escritura no prevalecía en el entorno `windows` he colocado esto para que lo actualice cada vez que intenta validarlo... si ocurre un error al ejecutar este permiso; entonces es por que el usuario no tiene los permisos. estaré agregando algo a symfony para lograr solucionar este problema ...

También descubrí el culpable: por alguna fantástica idea se me ocurrió crear el proyecto en una carpeta que se sincronizaba con google drive ... al parecer esto provoca algún tipo de conflicto por lo cual el error re-aparece; la solución definitiva fue sacar el proyecto de dicha estructura